Is this group action proper?
Given a transitive hamiltonian group action of a connected Lie group $G$ on a compact symplectic manifold $\mathcal{M}$ is this action necessarily proper?

A continuous action of a Lie group $G$ on a compact space is proper iff $G$ is compact.

And there is nothing I can use precisely to derive that the group is compact? That's my problem. I mean, all I got is a hamiltonian transitive action, maybe freeness?

Yes, sorry, I just edited the question to add the transitivity assumption. Though freeness is too restrictive, can I derive from the things that I have that, for instance, the set of group elements that map one point into another is compact? this will also imply that the group is compact given the manifold is second countable and Hausdorff.

Assuming compactness of point-stabilizers makes all the difference.

@MoisheKohan can you develop on that, please?

You should first edit your question according to the guidelines given here.
